# A major issue regarding jqueryui in my project

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a question regarding drag and drop functionality of jquery ui. I m building a web app where a user can build his own object by dragging part from the part area(shelf) on to the stage). This stage will contain a main component which will be mostly circular in nature on which these sub components/parts will be placed.

These parts are images of 200px x 400px with transparent background and are draggable. They can be dropped onto stage area. Now here is the issue i m facing:

When i drag these object and place it on stage area, due the such a large image height they tend to overlap the shelf area. This overlapping makes the parts in shelf area unselectable or non draggable. Additionally when many such parts are on stage it is difficult to select the desired part due to such overlapping.

Is there any solution by which i can overcome this overlapping issue.

development platform is jquery ui and .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to your elements when dropping them on your shelf to reduce their sizes.

You did not provide much information apart from the context, such as which plugin you using for the drag/drop.

I have made a quick example using [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). In the [drop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop), you add a css class to the dropped element, accessible through `ui.draggable`. You can also bind the [out event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-out), to remove the class in case your elements could be dragged out of the target.

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).addClass('small');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).removeClass('small');
    },
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/h2cBM/)**

I suppose you could adapt this method to you own implementation.

Comment: I m using jquery ui's dragable and dropable